# Aligning multiple lines of text in an align environment

Tags: align

I want to use the right side of an aligned environment to present the reason for the next line. 
If the explanation requires more than one line the alignment fails.
This could be eye-balled by adding a horizontal space but there should be a better way.

How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a + b &= \quad \text{short reason} \\
  c + d &= \quad \text{a really long and} \\
        &\phantom{=} \quad \text{complicated reason} \notag \\
  e + f \text{.}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

If you compile the above code you will see what I mean.
I can't figure out how to add compiled code to a question.
If you know how do add compiled code to the question, please do so.

[image]

Comment: You can make a screenshot of the result and add it as in image, clicking on the  6th icon in the edit toolbar the icon which  looks like a mountain).

Comment: You might also want to add a `&` on line 8 before `\text{.}`, because currently that line of the equation is a little bit further to the left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to use the `aligned` construct for the multi-line comments as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a + b &= \quad \text{short reason} \\
  c + d &= \quad \begin{aligned}[t]&\text{a really long and} \\
                                   &\text{complicated reason}\end{aligned}\\
  e + f \text{.}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the "long and complicated" text takes even more lines, the lines are really too far apart for it to be recognized easily as a unit.  a paragraphing approach (with ragged right text) is better.

Comment: Notably this solution also works in mathjax, which doesn't support `parbox`

Answer (score 8):

with use of `parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a + b &= \quad \text{short reason} \\
  c + d &= \quad \parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{
                    really long and complicated\\
                    reason in two lines} \\
  e + f &=\text{.}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

**supplement:**
considering comment of [barbara beton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton), the above  solution should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a + b & = \quad \text{short reason} \\
  c + d & = \quad \parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{\raggedright  % <--- 
                    really long and complicated\\
                    reason in two lines} \\
  e + f & = .
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

in this simple case result is the same as at the first case, however if there's really long word that can't fit on the first line, added `\ragged` will avoid wide spaces between words in the first line.

Comment: Another good way to solve this alignment problem.

Comment: although it's not obvious here, if there's a really long word that can't fit on the first line, it would be better to specify ragged right to avoid wide spaces in the first line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you very much for your comment. i consider it in my answer. now result will look better also at circumstances of very long words in text.

Comment: I think this is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on @AboAmmar's answer, but using an environment that takes text and paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a + b &= \quad \text{short reason} \\
  c + d &= \quad \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.8\textwidth}}
                    really long and\\
                    complicated reason
                 \end{tabular} \\
  e + f &=\text{.}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Of course, the `0.8\textwidth` might need tweaking...

Comment: Thanks. Typically the reasons are no more than two lines so I accepted AboAmmar's answer. But I will remember your answer if there are really, really long reasons.

Comment: @Jay It's AboAmmar's idea so he deserves the tick on principle!

Comment: I up-ticked AboAmmar's answer and accepted it as well.

Comment: the second group would really look better if the numbe were not dropped down a line.  (i would also prefer that the baseline of the text be the same as that of the math at the left, but that's more subjective.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using `\begin{center} line_one\\line_two \end{center}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
      \begin{equation}
        a + b = \quad \text{short reason}
      \end{equation}  
      \begin{equation}
        c + d = \quad \parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{
                        really long and complicated\\
                        reason in two lines}
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}
        e + f =\text{.}
      \end{equation}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result would be like below image (Green color is drawn by hand just for showing the page's border)
[image]

Comment: In the code you use `\parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{...}`, that is already suggested in the [answer by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441891/123129). Also, the question is about an `align` environment, so the equal signs should be aligned. This is not the case in your answer. The `equation` environment is not really suitable for several directly consecutive equations; there is `align` for that.